# Derived class cannot recognize inner class of base class

Tags: c++, inner-classes, derived-class

Can someone here tell me how to get the derived class method below to recognize the inner class `Option` from the base class?

```
template <typename T>
class Menu {
protected:
    class Option { };
    Option* first;
};

template <typename T>
class MenuSpecial : Menu<T> {
    template <typename U>
    void foo();
};

template <typename T>
template <typename U>
void MenuSpecial<T>::foo() {
//  Option* option;  // GCC 11.2 does not recognize type Option.
    Menu<T>::Option* option;  // GCC 11.2 complains: 'option' was not declared in this scope
}
```

Comment: **tl;dr** of the dupe: `typename Menu<T>::Option* option;`

Comment: Ah, just `typename` was missing.  Couldn't think of that.  Thanks.

Comment: Minor point about terminology: C++ doesn't have "inner" classes; it has nested classes. People coming from Java tend to talk about "inner" and "outer" classes, because those are part of the Java world, but they have peculiar semantics that aren't present in C++.